# Show element after pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my html page i have an element of class `.breadcrumb` which is above the fold, i want to hide this element before pageload. And then `.appendTo` in another element ID `#BreadcrumbSnippet`.

I have done the 2nd part, but the thing is it looks very odd when the page loads the breadcrumb moves where it supposed to be but in a very odd manner. so if i could hide the `.breadcrumb` and it only shows after page gets loaded and the div also appendTo in another div.

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".breadcrumbs").appendTo("#breadcrumbSnippet");
});
```

In CSS i added `display: none;` but it keeps hidden.

Comment: Maybe try adding `$('.breadcrumbs').show()`.

Comment: Try .css("display", "block")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(".breadcrumbs").appendTo("#breadcrumbSnippet");
    $(".breadcrumbs").show(); //or you can use  $(".breadcrumbs").attr("display","block");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".breadcrumbs").appendTo("#breadcrumbSnippet").show();
```